# xPages application load times are slow even after using XPagesPreload

Tags: xpages

I have an xpages aplication with 40 xpages, 60 custom controls and with cca. 50 java files(used in src ... package explorer)
To speed up application load I have used these two variables in notes.ini

```
XPagesPreload=1 
XPagesPreloadDB=account/w-apps.nsf 
(I use the latest 853FP1)
```

In the log I can see, that these vars are being used but despite this I alway have to wait cca 7 seconds for the first page being displayed(next time is fast). And when I don't use the application e.g. for hour its seems to me its being unloaded and then I have to wait once again. At the end, when you use application once in hour, you alway have to wait some time what is annoying. Is there a way how to speedup / overcome these things or at least to avoid the application unload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XPagesPreload` setting is weird and totally useless in my opinion. It will preload them only in the rare event of booting HTTP task or the server. If the XPage is not accessed for 2.5 hours it will be unloaded. I noticed this 2.5 hours when testing with 8.5.2. In Domino 9 I just know that they are unloaded after a few hours, probably it's still 2.5 hours.

I had a much bigger problem than 7 seconds loading time. It was 1-3 minutes the first time certain XPages were loaded. David Leedy also mentions similar loading times.

After some testing I found out that the slowness is caused by a View Panel where documents are fetched using full-text search and sorted (not sure if sorting is relevant). This causes the very long initial loading time **when the view index is large**. After the first time the page loads in 1-3 seconds with different full-text searches. Our view index was almost 0.7GB because of 12 columns sortable to both ways (customer requirement). The slowness was between `beforeRenderResponse` and `afterRenderResponse` events.

I doubted that the customer would use all these 24 sort indexes so I checked the "Defer index creation until first use" option in each column. Then I discarded the view index and it has stayed small so far and the first load in the morning is a few seconds now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with xPages. After a time period the server unloads your application to free up memory for other applications. The setting your are searching for is :

xsp.application.timeout

in the xsp.properties file in your nsf / server. If you change this number it would take longer to time out your server but be aware:

**It also means that memory is not cleared for sessions which could cause a outofmemory error.**

If your application takes 7 seconds to load there is a lot going on on the background. I think it is wise to first see if you can optimize your architecture, optimize the memory settings on the server ( jvm heapsize ) and see if the specs of your server are maybe the bottleneck..

Comment: But if I have ust one application on the server does it really mean thet without unloading I can encounter memory leaks? I think not because actively used application(where unload is not occuring)  is working fine ...

Comment: I think so. Take for instance the session scopes. These are unique for every member (and maybe even per login but I dont know the exact working of the sessionscopes) . Even anonymous users will get a session scope. If you dont unload your application imagine how many of these scopes will be created and how to pile up until the point the memory limit is reached and youre application (or even the server) crashes..

Comment: Well sessions have timeout and then are discarded. I also assume that application for 100 users cant crash my server.

Comment: I've seen initial delays on some of my apps as well.  Complaints from users that the first one in on the morning gets a LONG delay.  Maybe a couple minutes.  After that it's fine.

Comment: Is xsp.application.timeout working for you? I set it to 1440 minutes but still after some time (2,5 hours I believe) the XPages are unloaded and reopening takes a long time.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep session times modest, but use a scheduled agent that simply does a @URLOpen on one page that can be accessed as anonymous. This prevents the application from timing out. To do that set Anonymous to "no access" but check "read public document" and then check one page as "available to public access users". The page shouldn't do anything, just send back "OK - I got it" --- but keeps the application context alive.

If you schedule the agent to run from 08:00 - 18:00 your app is up during normal working hours

Comment: Is that really working for you? I have some complex Xpages (like @DavidLeedy) that take about 2 minutes to open the first time. After that they open in 5 seconds. I tested your solution by opening first some simple XPages from the application (with a browser). Then I waited for 7 minutes and opened a complex XPage and it still took 2 minutes to open.

Comment: preventing the application to time out keeps the application scope and your application scoped managed beans in memory. It doesn't influence the page cache for XPages. Depending on where the bulk of your logic is at home (hint: beans), it does help. Of course if the page itself is complex with tons of stuff, the load issue will reoccur

Comment: OK, no managed beans in use here. Looks like I need to open those large XPages which require login in background early in the morning.

Comment: Looks like you need some refactoring for performance (might contain beans)

Comment: This is the first time I hear using beans can be the solution for performance problems. Is there more info somewhere? Anyway the problem is (and has always been) only the first load of an XPage even when it does all the same things in subsequent loads.

Comment: When an XPage loads the first time the class is cached in memory and unloaded after some time - not to confuse with app timeouts. If your page takes long,  then it is heavy. By offloading logic to beans where you can control the caching and use lazy loading/execution you can make your page lighter. As usual : it depends. If your page simply has 300 fields beans won't help, you need to refactor your UI

Comment: Most of the code is Java but not managed beans. I guess I need to take a look at them. Anyway it's not **that** complex page that 2-3 minutes load time would be understandable. I need debug the XPage more (not created by me of course) and anyway we are going to reduce the amount of docs dramatically now.

Comment: Without scope bound Java objects (can be beans or otherwise) you have potentially uncached lookups. Happy refactoring!